# Download size of Docker images

Tags: docker

While pulling a Docker image, it downloads it in separate parts (layers). I need to get the download size of all necessary layers of an image before actually downloading it.

Is there a way to do it?

---

One can just be running the `docker pull` command and watch the output:

```
ffcacfbccecb: Downloading [+++++>    ] 14.1 MB/30.13 MB
ffcdbdebabbe: Downloading [++>       ] 1.1 MB/12.02 MB
```

So its download size is "42.15".

However I've got some options enabled to download layers one by one:

```
ffcacfbccecb: Downloading [+++++>    ] 14.1 MB/30.13 MB
ffcdbdebabbe: Waiting
```

So this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Always leave a comment while giving a down vote so the OP knows how to improve the question, especially to the questions, because you didn't waste any reputation of yours so you owe it to the OP :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Docker Hub API isn't documented publicly. But you can get a JWT to use for the API and then make a call to list out the tags to get the size. Here is an example using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse out the size in bytes:

First authenticate to get your token:

```
export HUBUSER=andyshinn
export HUBPASS=mypass
export HUBTOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${HUBUSER}'", "password": "'${HUBPASS}'"}' https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ | jq -r .token)
```

Now you can query the tags API to filter for a specific tag and get the size. In this example, we are getting the official library `wordpress` image and filtering out the `latest` tag:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/wordpress/tags/?page_size=100" | jq -r '.results[] | select(.name == "latest") | .images[0].size'
```

You should get back something like `169817871` which is the size of the entire image in bytes. This is a modified example from information found at https://gist.github.com/kizbitz/e59f95f7557b4bbb8bf2.

Comment: Worth to mention that we can pip the `curl` output to `numfmt --to=iec-i` to get a human readable number like: `162Mi`.

Answer (score 2):

@Andy's way is perfect. Thanks a lot! That does help me out.

1. In reference to his answer, I use the below command to get the compressed size of a Docker image hosted on Docker Hub:

   ```sh
   curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT " "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/<image-name>/tags/?page_size=100" | jq -r '.results[] | select(.name == "<tag-name>") | .images[0].size' | numfmt --to=iec-i
   ```
2. For an image on another registry, like Microsoft Container Registry, I figured out three ways:

   - Use `docker manifest inspect` to observe the manifest data, which can give you idea on how to gain the compressed size of the image.

     ```sh
     docker manifest inspect -v <registry-domain>/<image-name> | grep size | awk -F ':' '{sum+=$NF} END {print sum}' | numfmt --to=iec-i
     ```

     To enable `docker manifest inspect`, edit `~/.docker/config.json` file and set `experimental` to `enable`.(Reference: [Docker manifest inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest_inspect/))
   - Push the image to Docker Hub and you can get the compressed size of the image on the Docker Hub website.
   - Use `docker save` to save an image to a .tar file and then compress it a .tar.gz file.

     ```sh
     docker save my-image:latest > my-image.tar

     # Compress the .tar file
     gzip my-image.tar

     # Check the size of the compressed image
     ls -lh my-image.tar.gz
     ```

Answer (score 1):

you can go to Docker Page, exemple: [MySQL Container Tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags) as you can see in this image **[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiTHV.png)**
I hope it help you and other ones.

Answer (score 0):

However the answer provided by @Andy is more like a programmers' choice and a better way to do it. I usually use another way which I find easier and convenient.

I often use an online lab for testing the size and performance of Docker-image. My favorite is [play-with-docker](http://labs.play-with-docker.com/), which provides a terminal session of about 3 hours and you are free to do anything. Images get downloaded easily and very fast there. And after that I get all the information I require regarding the image, be it size or anything else. I can also see if that image suits my work or not by using it then and there.